# How can an int be an AssetManager?

Tags: c++

Why does this work?

```
AssetManager* am = (AssetManager*)env->GetIntField(obj, gAssetManagerOffsets.mObject);
```

`env->env->GetIntField()` returns an `Int`.  Why can it be converted to an AssetManager? This code is from the file `android_util_AssetManager.cpp`.

Comment: added c++ tag, think you will have a lot more luck with those guys :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The int being returned is a pointer to an AssetManager.  The `(AssetManager*)` tells you that it's a pointer to an AssetManager.

So, it's returning an int, which happens to be a pointer to an AssetManager.  It's not returning an AssetManager.

This [Tutorial on Arrays and Pointers in C](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) might help you.   Chapter 5 shows the syntax you're seeing in the code you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I check the code and found there is one line :   'env->SetIntField(clazz, gAssetManagerOffsets.mObject, (jint)am);'. So I understand it.

Comment: Great!  If my answer helped you, would you click the green checkmark to the left of it?  Thanks!